# classes and methods report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, architecture, visual-studio-extensions

Is there any tool or extension to generate a report which contains data about classes and  methods? For example, show a summary of all classes and the methods included in each class with the count of both.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found it in Visual studio. go to the following menu option

Analyze > Calculate Code Metrics for Solution

It will show Code Metrics Result window. From this window choose export to excel and you'll get a report with all the projects, Namespaces, Classes, Methods and some other details about them in Excel file.

Answer (score 3):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) lets you perform all kinds of queries about your code. I can't say I've used it myself, but I would be surprised if it didn't let you generate reports.

---

See reports generated by NDepend [here](http://www.ndepend.com/sample-reports/).

See explanations about NDepend code metrics [here](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics).

Also you can get all these result both in Visual Studio 2017, 2015, 2013, 2012, 2010, and also in [Visual Studio Team Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ndepend.ndependextension).